# Checking for a member in a many to many set in django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following user class,

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
```

And I've the following room object,

```
class Room(Base):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    status = models.CharField(default=RoomStatus.ACTIVE, max_length=255, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    last_activity = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

I'm trying to find if an user is present in the room as a member,

```
user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('user_id'))
room = Room.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('room_id'))
```

This doesn't work,

```
member = room.members.filter(user=user)
```

How can I do this correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a single query, you can filter on:

```
Room.objects.filter(id=kwargs['room_id'], members__id=kwargs['user_id']).exists()
```

Or if you need the `Room` and `User` anyway anyway:

```
room = Room.objects.get(id=kwargs['room_id'])
user = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('user_id'))
if user in room.members.all():
    # ...
    pass
```

You can also filter the `room.members` for `id=user_id`:

```
if room.members.filter(id=kwargs['user_id']).exists():
    # ...
    pass
```